# Open hyperlink after jquery scroll event

Tags: jquery, events, hyperlink, scroll

I'm looking for a script that automatically opens a hyperlink after a jquery scroll event. This is the script I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.anchorLink").anchorAnimate()
});

jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1300
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
}
```

The scrolling part is working fine but now I also want it to load another page after the scroll.

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [jquery waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) to trigger an automatic redirect after the scroll has reached the way point you define

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work since I have 5 buttons on the same page that need to redirect to different pages [link](http://edenbeach.pepperminds-marketing.com/index.php)

The related content need to be loaded in the space below the buttons